# Como eliminar duplicados con mongodb y python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

Tengo un scrapper que extrae datos de cierta plataforma y los guarda en mongo, la colección 'movies', contiene los diferentes jsons asi:

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("etcetc")
 "Id" : "etcetc", 
 "Title" : "titulo",  
 "Type" : "serie" (o "movie"), 
 "Year" : NumberInt(x), 
 "Duration" : NumberInt(x), 
 "Directors" : ['nombre1', 'nombre2'], 
 "Cast" : ['nombre1', 'nombre2'], 
}
```

como podria hacer una query con pymongo que me elimine los duplicados en base a mismo titulo, type y rango de año (por ejemplo hay titulos con igual title donde uno tiene año 2020 y otro 2019, por lo tanto el rango seria de 1 año como maximo), hasta ahora tengo la siguiente query: `mongo.db['movies'].aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': {'Title': '$Title', 'Type': '$Type'}, 'count':{'$sum': 1},'dups': {'$addToSet': '$_id'}},},{'$match': {'count': {'$gt': 1}}}])`
con esta consulta mongo me encuentra los duplicados pero no encuentro la solucion a aplicar ese "rango" entre year y year de cada contenido, es posible hacerlo con mongo?